# SharePoint Framework development using Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio, spfx, typescript

I am going through the new development approach that is introduced in SharePoint which seems to be open source and suggested approach by Microsoft.

If i look from developement perspective then it has introduced typescript and Yeoman tool to get started. I found good article providing guidance using Yeoman tool but I am looking forward to the possiblities of developement using Visual Studio.

Can you please let me know if there is any guidance on the visual studio development or how to get started? Also how would the deployement work if we develop the solution using Visual Studio

Comment: The last I heard Microsoft was considering adding SharePoint Framework development tooling to Visual Studio (i.e. File > New Project) but they had no estimates on when that work would start or when it would be available for developers to use.

Answer (score 3):

This question was posted 2 years ago.  I'm asking myself the same thing now, but it still appears that Visual Studio Code is the way most people go here.

Visual Studio 2019 includes the ability to do Node.js projects, but doesn't mention SharePoint Framework.  I'd guess that the method could be worked out, but personally I'm going to go with the approach that is more documented at this point - VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

There's some guidance on using Visual Studio as the development environment for SharePoint Framework (SPFx) client-side web parts at [https://dev.office.com](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-visual-studio)

The documentation is a little out of date as it still refers to the SharePoint Framework as being in preview. The documentation is also not terribly expansive!

It is likely that support for development in Visual Studio for client-side components will improve in time. At the moment, the preference of the PnP team seems to be to use VS Code instead as your development environment as mentioned in [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1)](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)